# Mathematica 11 Sneak Peeks from Wolfram European Technology Tour 2016

Tags: discussion

From the Wolfram Blog post [2016 Wolfram European Technology Tour Dates and Locations](http://blog.wolfram.com/2016/05/26/2016-wolfram-european-technology-tour-dates-and-locations/) it is mentioned that sneak peeks of *Mathematica 11* would be given. May someone share the improvements and new features that were shown.

Comment: …assuming there aren't NDAs being enforced.

Comment: @J.M. It has been my experience that the conferences are very open.  They don't tend to share what they don't want to be public.

Comment: [Here](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1111/wolfram-technology-conference-2013-sponsorship-proposal#comment4963_1114) is an example of enforcement of NDAs w.r.t. a Wolfram Technology Conference (@J.M.).

Comment: I've asked a friend who was at Warsaw's conference. He is not aware of any restrictions about sharing that info so here is something: it should be released in 2-6 months and a neural networks framework is supposed to be the leading feature.

Comment: The Wolfram staff were using *Mathematica* 11.x ("last nights *Mathematica*") during their presentations. For me the most exciting new things shown were in the machine learning area, which will keep evolving and being extended.

Comment: @Karsten7. Anything new that isn't already in the Python or MatLAB packages?

Comment: @Kuba 2-6 months seems very short ...

Comment: @Szabolcs that is what I was told. You mean "suspiciously short because .." or just "great, it is soon"? What I'm curious is why the spread is so big in such soon date.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Neither am I sufficiently familiar with the MATLAB Toolboxes and all the Python packages nor was the presentation extensive enough to give you a meaningful answer. I mainly meant new to *Mathematic*, not new to machine learning. It'll be your judgment if the symbolic nature of *Mathematica* adds something new, or if it's just different. Was [`ClusterClassify`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ClusterClassify.html?q=ClusterClassify) (introduced in 10.4) something new that's not already available in those packages?

Comment: @Karsten7. Have a look [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/)

Comment: @Karsten7. Anything new about differential equation solving and compiling?

Comment: @xzczd Differential equations and compiling were not on the [schedule](http://www.wolfram.com/events/europe-technology-tour-2016/schedule.html). I asked about the [next generation compiler](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P2tr7A1LOLA). It's considered a "long term project", which doesn't make me too optimistic for v11. (But I know nothing for sure and am looking forward to it.)

Comment: @Karsten7. At WTC 2015 there was a session on new kernel management features. Any mention of this in passing in any of the sessions.

Comment: @Edmund During the final Q&A someone asked if the technologies related to launching multiple kernels will be discontinued because of the cloud stuff and a better kernel management functionality was given as an example of coming improvements in that area. I can't recall hearing definite information about when.

Comment: I really hope there will be lots of speed improvements, especially regarding cuda features. Because this is the number one area mathematica has deficits.

Comment: @Wizard The fact that CUDA is used and needed for machine learning makes it an almost inevitable necessity.

Comment: @Karsten7., were there any mentions of the improvements in the time series analysis? May be support for multivariate models?

Comment: From an email announcing that my site will get MM 11 soon: "Major new functionality for 3D printing, audio processing, machine learning, and neural networks headlines the list of advancements in Mathematica 11."